# What is this 11.59 GB partition on my iMac?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

[image]

What is this 11.59 GB partition ?

Is that supposed to be there ? If not, what can it be and how can I remove it ?

I don't remember seeing it before I used Bootcamp and installed Windows. I installed Windows, it started crashing, and in the process of trying to fix and do a clean install of Windows, it seems that I crashed my Mac, too. And I am wondering if it's some sort of residue from a failed partitioning with Bootcamp.

Comment: Did you have any previous installations of macOS were the installation volume was stored in this APFS container? If so, then when you deleted the volume to remove the macOS installation, the files stored in these other volumes, that are associated with deleted volume, are not deleted. The files remain until you manually delete them.

Comment: @DavidAnderson no, I did not.